# Making Screen Saver Images full screen

Tags: macos, screensaver

I set up the screen saver to a folder containing some of my photos.

How do I get the screen saver in Mavericks to display them full screen?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Classic mode might not show full screen (depending on original size)

I would use the:

Ken Burns Option in the settings.

Go to System Preferences → Desktop & Screen Saver and choose Ken Burns mode.

There is some animation going in that mode but it is rather pleasing.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences → Desktop & Screen Saver and choose the Classic screen saver:

[image]